# glColor4f fails to set color?

Tags: c++, opengl

In my application for one particular case 
`glColor4f()` is not working.

1. If I use `glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_COLOR, color);` it will return previously set color value.
2. My current object is rendered with previous set color.

If I put `glFlush()` just before the `glColor4f()`, it works properly.

Also above issue is not reproducible when I use gDebugger, xCaptain, or Visual Studio to debug my application.

How should I proceed to get exact issue?

---

(From the comments)

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1) ; 
for (int i = nb_point - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    glRasterPos3f ( point[j], point[j+1], point[j+2]);
    glBitmap ( 9, 9, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, fontbits[symbol]); j += 3; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how you draw objects? There are too many possible explanations here to make make any meaningful comments.

Comment: glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1) ;
    for (int i = nb_point - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      glRasterPos3f ( point[j], point[j+1], point[j+2]);
      glBitmap  ( 9, 9, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, fontbits[symbol]);
      j += 3;
    }

Comment: Why on earth are you rasterising points this way? Why are you not using draw calls?

Comment: its old application , some legacy stuff. but main question is about glColor4f() and glFlush(), why such strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

When setting colors for the raster commands, you have to remember that they actually utilize a different state variable - `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_COLOR` instead of `GL_CURRENT_COLOR`.

The raster color gets the value of currently set color precisely when [`glRasterPos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml) is called.

> The current raster position also includes some associated color data and texture coordinates. If lighting is enabled, then `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_COLOR` (in RGBA mode) or `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_INDEX` (in color index mode) is set to the color produced by the lighting calculation (...)  If lighting is disabled, current color (in RGBA mode, state variable `GL_CURRENT_COLOR`) or color index (in color index mode, state variable `GL_CURRENT_INDEX`) is used to update the current raster color.

I'm not sure why `glFlush` is helping anything, though. You might need to narrow your code down to only reproduce the problem.

Comment: lighting is disabled so  `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_COLOR = GL_CURRENT_COLOR`  main question is why glcolo4f() is not working, and issue is unpronounceable when any debugger is attached

Comment: Most likely the debugger does a glFlush itself, or the delay introduced by the debugger generates an implicit flush.